# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] shows only domain name without www

Tags: php, apache

Even if in url i write "www.", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] have only domain.com without "www."

I can't redirect from non-www to www because of this. How to fix this issue?

```
      ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
      string(8) "ca-fi.ru"
      ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
      string(120) "d7b6b86aae18e551749a9da9d54f3daf=floar2lr37318dc76ask49bii5; 849c6485c12558d081c065b4d94a566b=d9iqj8s6oqo41kipg3qaefq497"
      ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
      string(99) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5"

      ["PATH"]=>
      string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
      ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
      string(69) "
    Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at ca-fi.ru Port 80

    "
      ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
      string(22) "Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)"
      ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
      string(8) "ca-fi.ru"
      ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
      string(13) "192.168.10.12"
      ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
      string(2) "80"
      ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
      string(12) "192.168.10.1"
      ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
      string(8) "/var/www"

      ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
      string(3) "GET"

      ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
      string(1) "/"
      ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
      string(10) "/index.php"
      ["PHP_SELF"]=>
      string(10) "/index.php"
      ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
      int(1338819407)
```

Comment: Are you doing echo or $var = ...; with what you're showing us?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is set with the Host header your client sends. If you are on `http://www.domain.com/`, the host header will have to contain the `www` part since the browser will send it.

Comment: can't add var_dump, because of "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: CodeCaster, they will have, but it hasn't

Comment: Given @Jeroens answer and your comment there, you seem to already have a redirect in place. If your `.htaccess` performs a redirect to the non-www host of your site, there's your answer.

Comment: Answer is correct for common issue, but in my case problem was in hosting coniguration, ISA blocking changes in $_SERVER and prevent to working redirect. But ok, he answer still may work for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to redirect from non-www to www, I'd recommend not using PHPs [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function (which I assume you're using), but to use [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Create a `.htaccess` file in your root directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? Have you replaced example.com with your domain name?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://chris.olstrom.com/howto/fix-canonical-problems-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: if i try this i get Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects

Comment: i try to find what wrong, but have no idea... i think it is all because of missing www in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], but cant fix this